# Problem with Google AJAX Search API RESTful interface

Tags: ajax, api, search, rest

When I send the following query

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/local?v=1.0&q=coffee%20New%20York%20NY
```

using c# WebClient.DownloadString function or ordinary web browser
I get JSON data which is different from data for the same query using JavaScript and
Google AJAX Search API.

From REST service I get the following url field

```
http://www.google.com/maps/place?source003duds0026q003dcoffee0026cid003d13245583795745066822
```

but from JavaScript query I get this url field

```
http://www.google.com/maps/place?source=uds&q=coffee&cid=13245583795745066822
```

The problem with REST service answer is that the url it gives points 
to a web page with error message "We currently do not support the location".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by parsing JSON data with Json.NET library http://json.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like either you are decoding the URI from the REST request incorrectly, or Google is ending it wrong.  The `=` are being sent or parsed as `003d` and the `&` as `0026`

EDIT : After trying that link I see they return the links, in the JSON, with the '=' and '&' encoded, the JavaScript must be replacing those characters for you automatically.  You could do a simple String replace on "003d" and "0026" - although I'm not sure that will cover every use case.